# Sci-fi fantasy book vampire anti-hero

Tags: story-identification, vampire

Need a book, or perhaps a series where starting hero is a "lazy priest" on a colonized world where manifestation of ID broke down technology. He meets up with an original colonist who in an attempt to hold back change, sacrificed his family and is now a vampire. Thus he has lived for thousands of years and is one of the few who remember technology. To the rest of the world it is all fairy tales and the reality is what we know as fantasy with demons, magicians, clerics, and such.

Comment: Why do you call Damien (the priest) lazy?

Comment: If why, what I remembered is perhaps more reluctant, but without the recent info, lazy was what I remembered

Answer (score 5):

I think the book you are looking for is "Black Sun Rising" by C. S. Friedman.  You can read about it on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0756403146) or [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_Sun_Rising).

Comment: You beat me by two minutes.

Comment: You're quite welcome.